# Admob bannner ads not taking full width

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

Neither test nor live ads are taking full width of the device when using Admob banner ads.

**This is the `adView` that i've declared in my layout xml:**

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

**This is what is rendered:**

[image]

Comment: The ad quite clearly states that it's 320px wide.

Comment: @AdamS So how can i make it occupy the full width?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Change

```
ads:adSize="BANNER"
```

to

```
ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
```

> Smart Banners are new ad units (as of v6.0.0) that will render
>   screen-wide banner ads on any screen size across different devices in
>   either orientation. Smart Banners help deal with increasing screen
>   fragmentation across different devices by "smartly" detecting the
>   width of the phone in its current orientation, and making the ad view
>   that size.

[Read more here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner#smart_banners)

Comment: `AdSize.SMART_BANNER` is now deprecated. I would suggest using `AdSize.FULL_BANNER` instead.

Answer (score 5):

you can use FULL_WIDTH

example `ads:adSize="FULL_WIDTHx50"`

Comment: This solution is best because smart_banner can get more than 50px height it will take care of height of ad.

Comment: What is the equivalent through the Java API? Edit: `adView.setAdSize(new AdSize(AdSize.FULL_WIDTH, 50));`

Answer (score 1):

You can use SmartBanner but remember, some times ads don't have full width and center in container (when using SmartBanner), so don't scare.

Answer (score 1):

Solution

```
ads:adSize="BANNER"
```

to

```
ads:adSize="FULL_BANNER"
```

Chill Pill:)